# How to derive code from crate/module/functions?

Tags: rust, code-generation

As far as I know, Rust supports `#[derive]` attribute to generate code at compile time from data structures. How can I generate code for whole crate, module or functions? The `#[derive]` attribute is not allowed here.

I want to generate a function which involves multiple items (structs/enums/functions) in the project.

For example, for given example module here

```
#[derive(MyAgg)]
mod AAA {
    struct BBB {}
    struct CCC {}
    fn ddd() {}
}
```

I want to produce this.

```
fn example1() {
    print("{:?}", AAA::BBB {});
    print("{:?}", AAA::CCC {});
    AAA::ddd()
}
```

This example doesn't make sense, but I think it delivers the point.

Answer (score 3):

The `#[derive]` attribute is not allowed on modules, only on structs, enums and unions:

```
error: `derive` may only be applied to structs, enums and unions
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | #[derive(MyAgg)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cbc226524dad98e08d81ab618a5ddd4b&version=stable&mode=debug)

Further information on extending the `#[derive]` macro can be found in [Procedural Macros (and custom Derive)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html) in the Rust book.

However, you could create your own procedural macro. You may consult the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1566-proc-macros.md) to understand *proc-macros*. It wouldn't hurt to also take a look at other crates like [Serde](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) or [Derivative](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/).

Comment: The book link you give only talks about custom derive. Can you make a procedural macro that *isn't* a custom derive?

Comment: @trentcl Yes, you can. The most popular examples are [Serde](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) and [Derivative](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/).

Comment: It seems function-like macro can be implemented in two different ways. Template-like or by editing tokens.

Comment: Any manually created custom procedural macros (function like, derive, attribute) may only be applied to structs, enums and unions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. You can spawn a Rust language parser and parse source code yourself.

First, add a dependency to `Cargo.toml`.

```
[dependencies]
syntex_syntax = "0.59.1"
```

And add these lines to `src/main.rs`.

```
extern crate syntex_syntax;

use std::path::*;
use syntex_syntax::parse::*;
use syntex_syntax::codemap::*;

fn main() {
    let f = file!(); // Get absolute path to this file.
    let p = Path::new(f);
    let m = FilePathMapping::empty();
    let s = ParseSess::new(m);
    let r = parse_crate_from_file(&p, &s);
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

Now you have a parsed AST.

---

Update

After several weeks of tries, I learned macro-expansion is done at syntax parsing stage. As it gets executed before type analysis stage, I cannot query fully resolved paths for each types, therefore stable referencing of multiple types from multiple module becomes very hard or impossible. Finally, I abandoned macro-based approach.